# How to fix routes with similar patterns

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to create these url structures.

```
1) domain.com/city/a-really-long-slug/optional-page
2) domain.com/city/optional-parameter/query-string-appended-string
```

How do I fix second route? 
It works if I provide optional parameter but it fails if I skip optional parameter.

```
domain.com/city/query-appended-string
Fails! (Catches first route. Expects query-appended-string to be a slug)

domain.com/city/optional-parameter/query-appended-string
Works!
```

Routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{city_name}', 'middleware' => 'MyMiddleware'], function(){
    Route::get('{slug}/{page?}', array('as' => 'url-structure-1', 'uses' => 'HomeController@createProfile'))
    ->where(array(
        'city_name'   => '[a-zA-Z ]+',
        'page'   => '((?i)photos(?-i)|(?i)videos(?-i)|(?i)reviews(?-i)|(?i)more(?-i))',
        'slug'  => '[a-zA-Z-]+'
    ));
    Route::get('{area?}/{query}-appended-string', array('as' => 'url-structure-2', function($city_name, $area="default", $query){
        return func_get_args();
    }))
    ->where(array(
        'city' =>   '[a-zA-Z-]+', 
        'area' =>   '[a-zA-Z-]+', 
        'query',    '[a-zA-Z-]+'
    ));
});
```

Comment: How do you plan to differentiate those routes? Can't you add a keyword to the second route?